# Google Timeline duplicated timesheets in a row

Tags: google-visualization, duplicates

I generate a Timeline with data of a SQL query. I use various timesheets in the same row. The problem is, that sometimes I get same timesheet from two different query in a row, so these are in full cover. In this case I would like to see only one.
Is there a built in feature in the API to handle this situation?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVClR.jpg

Comment: Please focus on the problem, instead of giving -1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are clever people and there people, who would like to seems clever...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain that this will work, but you could try grouping your data before drawing the chart:

```
// the first array should contain a list of all of your column indicies, the second should be empty
var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0, 1, 2, 3], []);
```

This will create a DataTable identical to your original, except any rows that are exact duplicates will be reduced to a single row.

It is probably faster to handle this in SQL than in javascript, though.